# CMake: How deep copy a list of strings

Tags: cmake

When I use set to copy a list of strings I get a reference instead of a deep copy, because when I remove some items from my new list variable, elements are removed from the original list too.

My code looks like the following snippet:

```
set(NEW_LIST ${TARGET_NAME}_SRC_FILES)
message("new list content1    : ${${NEW_LIST}}")
list(REMOVE_ITEM ${NEW_LIST} ${${TARGET_NAME}_LIN64_EXCLUDED_SRC_FILES})
message("new list content2    : ${${NEW_LIST}}")
message("original list content: ${${TARGET_NAME}_SRC_FILES}")
```

First print give me the full list before the removal and both following are shorter and identical.

I am looking for something that will not alter the original list.

Edit:
I updated the upper code snippet and the lists are filled like this:

```
set( ${TARGET_NAME}_SRC_FILES
     foo.cpp
     foo2.cpp)
```

Comment: Looks like your understanding of "list" differs from CMake's list variable.  CMake's list variable is set as `set(list_var "first_elem" "second_elem")`, and can be printed with `message("List: ${list_var}")`. But you dereference a variable **twice**... How variable `ORIGINAL_LIST` in your example is filled? Or is it a parameter to some function/macro?

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks

Comment: You helped me to understand my issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operation

```
set(NEW_LIST ${TARGET_NAME}_SRC_FILES)
```

assigns `NEW_LIST` variable to the **name of a variable** `${TARGET_NAME}_SRC_FILES`.

So *double* dereference of `NEW_LIST` returns a value of `${TARGET_NAME}_SRC_FILES` variable.

```
# Prints value of '${TARGET_NAME}_SRC_FILES' variable.
message("new list content1: ${${NEW_LIST}}")
```

For assign value of one variable to another one, you need to dereference the variable:

```
 set(NEW_LIST ${${TARGET_NAME}_SRC_FILES})
 # Now NEW_LIST variable contains current value of '${TARGET_NAME}_SRC_FILES' one.
 # Possibly modify '${TARGET_NAME}_SRC_FILES' variable...
 # ... but content of NEW_LIST variable remains the same
 message("new list content1: ${NEW_LIST}")
```